# Mysql Join - Get result in same row

Tags: mysql, inner-join, union

```
SELECT COUNT(status) AS COUNT
FROM financeinstallment
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY financeId
UNION
SELECT finance.financeId,
       finance.customerId,
       customer.customerName,
       customer.phone1,
       customer.aadhaar,
       finance.financeStartDate,
       finance.vehicleNumber,
       finance.loanAmount,
       finance.totalInstallment,
       finance.InstallmentAmount
FROM finance
INNER JOIN customer ON customer.customerId = finance.customerId
```

How to get the result in the same row?

**I got the below error:**

> Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns    0.000 sec

Comment: Sample input data, along with the output you want to see, would greatly help your question.

Comment: I need to get the two select query value in single row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach here might be to join the second query in the union to the first as a subquery.

```
SELECT
    t.count,
    f.financeId,
    f.customerId,
    c.customerName,
    c.phone1,
    c.aadhaar,
    f.financeStartDate,
    f.vehicleNumber,
    f.loanAmount,
    f.totalInstallment,
    f.InstallmentAmount
FROM finance f
INNER JOIN customer c
    ON c.customerId = f.customerId
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT financeId, COUNT(status) AS count
    FROM financeinstallment
    WHERE status = 1
    GROUP BY financeId
) t
    ON f.financeId = t.financeId;
```